# Can I use ivy dependency info in my ant build file

Tags: ant, hudson, ivy, archiva

In my ivy.xml file I have dependency statements like:

```
<dependency conf="*->*" org="gnu" name="gcc" rev="4.2.1" changing="false">
    <artifact name="gcc" ext="tbz2" e:classifier="src"/>
</dependency>
```

'rev=' can be a fixed value or 'latest' or whatever.

In my build file I would like to get hold of the value of 'rev' to be uses in further work flow after resolve is run.

Is there any way to do that or read a property for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [artifactproperty](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactproperty.html) task

```
<ivy:artifactproperty name="version.[artifact]" value="[revision]"/>

<echo message="gcc version: ${version.gcc}"/>
```

Comment: Ahh.. should have read the manual better. Works lik a charm :-) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. There are quite a few obscure gems hidden in the ivy documentation. Other useful tasks to check are: cachepath, buildlist, buildnumber